# Precedence constraint in SSIS is not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Precedence constraint in SSIS is not working as expected. I am not sure what I am missing?

**Expected results**: If expression is not true then next task should not be executed but in this case package executes the next component(Load Date) and failed it because NULL value is passed in DFT. I want to stop the execution if expression doesn't evaluate True.

[image]

Insert Message expression"-- ISNULL(@[User::vEndActivityDateTime]) || @[User::vEndActivityDateTime] =="0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000000

"Get Last Date constraint expression" -- !ISNULL(@[User::vEndActivityDateTime] )   ||  @[User::vEndActivityDateTime] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000000"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SSIS variables don't support null so the `ISNULL` function won't work here.  It looks like you want to use the default value of 0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000, however this isn't a valid value for the SSIS datetime variable data type.  I'd suggest picking another value that will never occur in your data as the default.  In the example below 1900-01-01 is used.
You can set this as 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000, however it will revert back since this defaults as the same value either way.  A default value for your variable can be set in the Value column of the variables pane (you don't need to use the Expression column next to it) and then set your precedence constraint to check for this default value using an expression like below.

**Variable:**
[image]

**Precedence Constraint Expression:**

```
@[User::vEndActivityDateTime] != (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000"
```